# how to show image just after uploading in django form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model of `image` and I want that when a user uploads the image field of the model the image should be shown in the form so that user can confirm the uploaded image but I didn't find any easy solution to do this task.
Please show me what is the good and easy way to implement this functionality.

Comment: You can do this by javascript & provide some code

Answer (score 2):

Well this can be achieved with a very few lines of javascript.

**HTML**

```
 <input type="file" accept="image" id="img-input"/>
 <img id="display-img"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
const imgInput = document.querySelector("#img-input")
const displayImg = document.querySelector("#display-img")
displayImg.src = URL.createObjectURL(imgInput.files[0])
```

*Or more practical way is to add event listner on img input ->*

```
const imgInput = document.querySelector("#img-input")
const displayImg = document.querySelector("#display-img")
imgInput.addEventListener('change',(event)=>{
   const imgObject = event.target.files[0]
   displayImg.src = URL.createObjectURL(imgObject)})
```

*And also check this code snippet.*

```js
const imgInput = document.querySelector("#img-input")
const displayImg = document.querySelector("#display-img")
imgInput.addEventListener('change',
(event)=>{
   const imgObject = event.target.files[0]
   displayImg.src = URL.createObjectURL(imgObject)})
```

```html
<input type="file" accept="image" id="img-input"/>
 <img id="display-img"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
#display-image{
  width: 400px;
  height: 225px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

html:

```
<input type="file" id="image-input" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/jpg">

<div id="display-image"></div>
```

js:

```
const image_input = document.querySelector("#image-input");
image_input.addEventListener("change", function() {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
    const uploaded_image = reader.result;
    document.querySelector("#display-image").style.backgroundImage = `url(${uploaded_image})`;
  });
  reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
});
```

When the input image field changes, the load event get fired. the selected image will be set as the background of the div with id display-image..